# Route53 domain name purchased in one account and have record set in another?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have purchased a route53 domain name in one account. Now I want to have the ability to create the record set and other things in another AWS account.

The reason is that I want the domain purchase in one account and have the ability to set the individual record set in the AWS account which is hosting the other resources.

How can I do this? Is there any disadvantage for this approact?

Comment: it does'nt matter where you have purchased your domain, you can always map the nameservers of domain name to any dns service

Answer (score 1):

If you have purchased the Domain name through Route53, you should be able to see the nameserver configurations under Registered domains.

- Go to Route53 in AWS Web Console.
- In the navigation pane, choose Registered Domains
  -Choose the name of the domain for which you want to edit settings.
- Choose Add/Edit Name Servers.
- In the Edit Name Servers dialog box, you can edit it to point to any other Hosted Zone.

Note: When you purchase the domain from Route53, it automatically creates the Hosted Zone under the same account and updates the name server configurations.

In your case if you want to create a new Hosted Zone in the other AWS account, create a new Hosted Zone there and update the name server details in domain purchased account.

> Is there any disadvantage for this approact?

I don't see any disadvantages of your approach. We also do this so that its easier to manage all the domain purchases under one account. Then delegates to different AWS account Hosted Zones to give control over them.

Comment: This really helps. Didnt see the 'Registered Domain' option before. I was trying to change NS. Your suggestion works. Thanks a ton. Sorry, I dont have enough point to give you an upvote.A newbie here.